# Remote access to Cpanel

Tags: security, api, cpanel

I would like to enable my users (who are already authenticated in my application) to automatically log into their Cpanel accounts through API.
If I know the password of the specific account, then it will be no problem. However, I do not think that I can retrieve the password of any account? If I can, please tell me which API function to use? If not, what can I do to achieve what I want?

Thanks

Elcin

Comment: I realized that  I can use https://11.111.111.11:2087/xfercpanel/accountname for this purpose. However, the opended page has this warning  "Warning! You are logged in with the reseller or root password". I do not want this. I want the user to login to his/her own panel and user level.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like cPanel has a method for providing secure remote logins as documented here: http://docs.cpanel.net/twiki/bin/view/AllDocumentation/SecureRemoteLogins
You can find the source for it in `/usr/local/cpanel/Cpanel/LogMeIn.pm`

I have a PHP implementation of `LogMeIn.pm` ready to go (easy to understand and port to any other language) <s>but I'm clearing it with the legal folks over at cPanel before I share it.</s>

After speaking with cPanel's VP of Operations, `LogMeIn.pm` is now dual-licensed allowing modification and use elsewhere as long as a copyright and license notice stays intact.

My PHP port can be found here: https://gist.github.com/4440574 I decided to implement it as a static class to closely resemble the original but you can very easily turn it into a procedural function.

Using it is as easy as

```
LogMeIn::getLoggedInUrl('username', 'password', 'example.com', 'cpanel');
```

which will return `false` on failure, and on success a string with a URL that will log the user in.

If you're running PHP 5.3.0 or greater you can add this to a cPanel namespace (add `namespace cPanel;` on the line after `<?php`) to keep it from conflicting with anything in your application that you've already written (or will write).